# django sorl-thumbnail json

Tags: django, json, sorl-thumbnail

I am using Sorl-Thumbnail to generate thumbnails within pages via template tags.
This all works perfectly fine.

However I have now added a store locator function to the site which feeds into my Google Maps JS via JSON.

In the infowindow popups I would like to put a tiny image of the storefront.
So I need to create another size of thumbnail and I need to include the URL for this within my JSON.

It seemed initially that Sorl doesnt support this due to its requirement for Tags within a page.

I have looked at the low level API version "get_thumbnail" and have tried to implement this within my Model without much luck so far.

I have no problem with my JSON and serialisation, just getting the thumbnail generated and into the model prior to this.

Has anyone had any experience with this scenario previously?

Cheers
Kev